# Connecting to two data sources for an Excel SQL connection

Tags: sql, excel, vba, connection

I have a SQL query that I'm successfully able to run in SSMS. It does, however require me to connect to two different sources. I've made the sources a simple name so I'm not sharing company data.

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 
    tbl1.[PartNumber],
    tbl1.[PartDescription],
    tbl1.[PartDescriptionLong],
    tbl1.[PhaseNumber],
    tbl2.FULL_NAME
FROM 
   [hidden1].[hid1].[table1Name] AS tbl1
   LEFT JOIN
   [hidden2].[hid2].[table2Name] as tbl2
   ON
   tbl2.USER_NAME=tbl1.ProductManager
```

In other cases, I've been able to use the below code in Excel VBA to connect to a source of data, and then execute a query that then populates a table.

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
Dim wkStation As String: wkStation = VBA.Environ("computername") 

With ws.ListObjects.Add( _
                    SourceType:=xlSrcExternal, _
                    Source:=Array("OLEDB;", _
                                  "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;", _
                                  "Integrated Security=SSPI;", _
                                  "Persist Security Info=True;", _
                                  "Data Source=SourceAddress;", _
                                  "Use Procedure for Prepare=1;", _
                                  "Auto Translate=True;", _
                                  "Packet Size=4096;", _
                                  "Workstation ID=" & wkStation & ";", _
                                  "Use Encryption for Data=False;", _
                                  "Tag with column collation when possible=False;", _
                                  "Initial Catalog=catalogName"), _
                    Destination:=ws.Range("A1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = sql
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

The 10th line down is this `"Data Source=SourceAddress;"` and that works great when I have just 1 data source. But when I have 2 I have no idea what to do. Any help would be much appreciated.